# TabSheet and middle click on tab

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Is there a way how to implement/attach middle click listener on tabs on TabSheet component? I would like to use it for closing tabs.

Comment: Good question. I tried to do this but `TabSheet` fires an event only during tab change, so it can't be used to close current tab. But we can use simple `tabsheet.getTab(tabComponent).setClosable(true);` to add close button to the tab.

Comment: Yes we use setClosable method, but middle click would be a nice addittion as it would allows us to create a closable feature similar as users close browser tabs.